# Smoothed shading surface looks triangulated

Tags: mesh, displacement, subdivision-surface, error, experimental-features

Surface of my subdivided and smoothed mesh looks triangulated.
The surface isn't flat it's displaced by Displacement output node with the **Vertex Paint** and some random values.

**How to make it look smooth?**

Is it experimental true displacement mode issue?

Thanks.

**UPD**
I made a test with the two meshes and those one that displaced by Displacement output node and **Vertex Paint** value had a sharp edge. Is this experimental bug?

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you set viewport smooth shading? (from left toolbox) I dont't  think it's displacement ( I see the displacement effect, but is different, on one corner of each tile)

Comment: to make micropolygon displacement work, your SubSurf modifier needs to be set to 'adaptive'. Then you need to make sure the settings under Render -> Geometry are fine enough for Viewport tessellation., plus the Shader itself has to be set to 'True'. In your screenshot, the 'adaptive' checkbox is not checked, so I'd start there.

Comment: @m.ardito Sorry, I don't understand what viewport smooth shading you're talking about? The viewport is set to render preview, and I get the same result after final render. The mesh set to smooth from object mode and from edit mode (i guess it's the same).

Comment: Guys, thanks for your answers. I don't need to micropolegon displacement here. And I guess the problem is experimental mode. I made a test with the two meshes: one of them is displaced by Displaced output and another just have a curved mesh. And guess what? https://monosnap.com/file/pJRrjuO5EYhKdlq87EhvTH8FALCLrE

Comment: @Ilya Kanatov I was talking about this very basic face smooth setting https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/smoothing.html just to be sure...

Comment: @m.ardito rest assure I did that, thanks)